# E/AndroidRuntime error with ImageButton

Tags: android, onclicklistener, imagebutton, findviewbyid

I'm trying to handle 3 ImageButtons on my onClick function. but my application crashes and that's what I get on my logcat :

```
03-17 21:30:25.372: E/AndroidRuntime(17838):    at me.hicham.resume.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:32)
```

it points to the line where i've set my ImageButton :

```
ImageButton fb_button = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_facebook);
```

I don't see what might cause this problem (logcat error is not clear enough).

here is my class :

```
package me.hicham.resume;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import me.hicham.resume.R;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

public HomeFragment(){}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    ImageButton fb_button = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_facebook);
    fb_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton tw_button = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_twitter);
    tw_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton ln_button = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_linkedin);
    ln_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    /*cool stuff in here*/

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent socialintent;

    if (v.getId()== R.id.button_facebook){
        socialintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://"));
        this.startActivity(socialintent);

    }
    else if (v.getId()== R.id.button_twitter){
        socialintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://"));
        this.startActivity(socialintent);

    }
    else if (v.getId()== R.id.button_linkedin){
        socialintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"));
        this.startActivity(socialintent);

    }       
}


}
```

Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make all of your `findViewById` calls on `rootView`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    ImageButton fb_button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_facebook);
    fb_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton tw_button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_twitter);
    tw_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton ln_button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_linkedin);
    ln_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}
```